# Rotate video bug in fullscreen with css

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I have lot of video need to be flip horizontal or vertical in fullscreen. Normally, i used css transform like rotateX(180 deg) or scaleX(-1) and it works on most of different computers on any browser. But in some computer, if fullscreen the video is not flip/rotate correctly, i have to change the rotate value to 174deg to make it works, because if i go over 174deg it will flip to the original. I can't figure out why that behavior happens. I tried on many OS, browser, browser version but i can't reproduce the bug... Is anyone experiencing the same problem like me?

Comment: Could you make a snippet which shows the problem? Are you rotating about the x axis as in your question?

Comment: The problem is it happen with some computer, not all. And it happens with both axis. I tried turn on inspect mode on bugged computer, change the rotate value one by one and it flip over when i increase the value from 174deg to 175deg just like flip from 180deg to 181deg in normal computer. So i think a snippet won't help. You can try it on every html5 video on fullscreen, if you dont get the bug then your computer is not bug.

Comment: I can’t try it at all without a snippet. Also, it would be useful for you to keep a record of what browser and OS you do and don’t see it on.

Comment: Then here is the snippet : https://pastebin.pl/view/d65561b5

If you press F11 to go fullscreen ( to keep the floating button ) and press the FLIP button, if it doesnt flip the video like in not fullscreen then there is the bug.

I notice that in the computer that got bug, if i change the video size to 99% or the body margin to more than 2 the bug is gone... So strange

Comment: Or i can fix by setting the container div padding to more than 4pixel. Seems like if the video is not fully fullscreen the video can be transform correctly.